How to run a DoE when multiple data points are collected from each leg?
I have a batch process with 4 parameters. I wish to run a DoE to understand how sensitive the output is to these parameters. I typically produce 15 samples with each setting. I use Minitab to create, and analyze the experiment. I would like to use a Full Factorial design (or Plackett Burman or even a Response Surface setup). I am not able to use a format that will allow me to analyze 15 samples as the result of one process. I don't think these are replicates (because they will be run sequentially under one leg). Is there a better setup? A Taguchi design perhaps?

You may want to clarify the question. You say you have 4 parameters; how many levels at each parameter? You also say that you produce 15 samples with each setting: I assume that a "setting" is a given combination of the parameters under study. If that is true (else, please clarify), then you indeed have 15 replicates (that is exactly the definition of replicates for DOE's). So then Minitab should easily let you create a full factorial DOE design (assuming only 2 levels for each parameters), that would give 240 total data points: 16*15).
